# Is it possible to implement .Equals for a Guid data type with EF 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I don't want to use '==', I want to use .Equals, this will allow me to do some more complicated stuff with generics.

At bare minimum I want to be able to execute this query without getting a NotSupportedException. I'd like to implement .Equals to work with a Guid just like it works with primitive types such as int, bool, and string. I've done similar stuff with NHibernate for implementing custom methods to build queries, and am hoping to be able to do the same with EF.

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
_dbContext.MyEntityType.Single(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
```

Comment: I explained that in the first sentence.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve (I mean the "more complicated stuff with generics").

Comment: _dbContext.GetById<MyEntityType>(myId); is the final goal I want to get to. But before doing that I am trying to get _dbContext.GetById(_dbContext.MyEntityDbSet, myId); working first and progress towards the final function once that is working. I want to put some custom logic in my GetById function also, it's not just going to be a simple .Single call.

Comment: @James Speaking generically, try building `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` using `Expression.Equal` as body.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks Ivan.

Comment: Btw, `Guid.Equals` perfectly works in latest EF6.1.3 Are you sure you are not calling `object.Equals`?

Comment: I am calling .Equals on the object. Which is supported for primitive types and enums.

Comment: Sorry Ivan, I meant that I was calling .Equals on the Id property, which is Guid, not the Entity object.

Comment: Then it should work. I mean, the sample snippet you've posted just works. Give it a try. I guess you are doing something else wrong, or using outdated EF version. This doesn't invalidate Servy's answer, but the concrete unsupported case does not exist (or has been fixed). You might consider posting another question with concrete code that is causing problems.

Comment: I'll create a new question and get you a link, my EF version is 6.1.3.

Comment: Ah Ivan, I tested it with Guid and it works as long as you're not using generics. Once you start using generics and your constraint demands a struct, if that struct type is a Guid, it will give NotSupportedException.

Comment: I think I'm just going to give up on a generic implementation, I've wasted enough time on it as it is.

Comment: There you go. How about putting constraint on `TId` like `where TId : struct, IEquatable<TId>`? You definitely need another more concrete question (see my previous comment) :)

Comment: I can't use IEquatable because some of my TId types are enum. My id types so far are int, Guid, and enums. I think I'm going to skip the question for this one, it's just too much effort for this, I'm just going to suck it up and have a bit of duplicate code, lol. I really do appreciate you taking the time to help though, thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Guid` *does* implement an `Equals` method already.  In this case it's EF that doesn't support transforming your specific usage into SQL, so unless you plan on writing your own query provider, you can't make it understand how to translate that code.  All you can do not write expressions that it doesn't know how to turn into SQL, which in this case means writing `==` in your expression (if that's what EF knows how to translate) rather than `Equals`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, thanks. I was hoping EF had an easy way of building queries from custom methods like NHibernate does, but it doesn't look that way.

Comment: @James It does.  Use `==`.  That's pretty easy.

Comment: See my comment section in the question on why I don't want to use ==. All I want to assume about my Id property is that is a struct. Regardless of what my reasoning of why I want to do this, it is silly that EF doesn't provide a means to do it.